# Alt+B, clipping border, not working

Tags: clipping

Suddenly I can't parts of the mesh with alt+B, don't understand why? Please see video for further info. I use the short commande alt+B.
https://youtu.be/qY4xIh-qA_s

Answer (score 1):

Oh... I was in *Material Preview* in *Viewport Shading*. Apparently clipping border does not show there. Went back to *Solid* in *Viewport Shading* and all is good.